# Remove empty elements in deep subarrays of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter

I would like to filter part of a multidimensional array. I have used the `array_filter` function. When I print the filtered data, it shows correctly, but I can't seem to save the data back to the array.

Here is the multidimensional array (called `$posted_product_details`) beforehand, containing the internal array (`[data]`) which I would like filter:

```
Array
(
[column_1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Colour
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Blue
                [1] => Green
                [2] => Red
                [3] => Yellow
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
            )

    )

[column_2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Pack QTY
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 3
                [3] => 3
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
            )

    )

[column_3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Product Code
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 65030
                [1] => 65029
                [2] => 65028
                [3] => 65031
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
            )

    )

[column_4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Barcode
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5099570650307
                [1] => 5099570650291
                [2] => 5099570650284
                [3] => 5099570650314
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
            )

    )

[column_5] => Array
    (
        [name] => 
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 
                [2] => 
                [3] => 
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
            )

    )

)
```

Here I attempt to loop through the array and filter the data:

```
foreach ($posted_product_details as $column => $info) {
    $name = $info['name'];
    $data = $info['data'];
    $info['data'] = array_filter($data);
}
```

However, upon printing the array afterward, the array has not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value by reference to modify the original array:

```
foreach ($posted_product_details as $column => & $info) {
    $name = $info['name'];
    $data = $info['data'];
    $info['data'] = array_filter($data);
}
```

This will correctly filter the `data` part of your array. However, if you need to filter out deeper elements, you'll have to use a recursive function, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9895181/1438393).

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/68042)

Answer (score 0):

The foreach construct makes a copy of each piece of the array as you iterate over it.  You have to explicitly call the original array to edit it:

```
$posted_product_details[$column]['data'] = array_filter($data);
```