# Delete empty value from array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array,  and I need to delete the empty value and just keep the other values.

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] =>  Philippines
            [2] => 94,013,200
            [3] => Mid-2010
            [4] => 0.0136
        )
    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )
```

Comment: use `unset()`  on 13th element of your array.

Comment: `$postArr = array_map('array_filter', $postArr);
$postArr = array_filter( $postArr );`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Remove empty array elements from a multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895130/php-remove-empty-array-elements-from-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: thank you but not 13th all time, maybe sometimes i have empty 10 and 11

Comment: Hi issam90, if it is'nt isset() then unset() :-)

Comment: Meaning, you cycle through your array with a foreach loop, if you find that an element is not set (isset() is false), you unset() that element. It is then destructed/removed from the array :-)

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer if yur issue has resolved chose the best one

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map` and `array_filter` functions for removing empty values from multi-dimensional array.

**Solution:**

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $yourArr));
```

**Example:**

```
$yourArr[12] = array('12','Philippines');
$yourArr[13] = array('','');
$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $yourArr));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => Philippines
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$result = array_map('array_filter', $a)
```

array_filter() removes blank elements from array in this case.

array_map() function calls a function on every array element, in this cause, it calls array_filter() and removes empty elements.

**Working Code:**

```
<?php
$a = array(12 => array(12, 'Philippines', '94,013,200', 'Mid-2010', '0.0136'), 13 => array('', '', '', '', ''));
$result = array_map('array_filter', $a);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter()` and `array_map()` to remove all empty and null value or array by using this logic

### Data:

The data contain **empty value**, **null value**, **0 value**, or empty array element.

```
$records = [ 
    [
        2567317.0,"123123Z23",3752.0,"OOO qwasww","446691087", "M3F23O00431","860030362370389282",321229.63,"20230116","sdfsdf",2501217.0,0.0456
    ],
    [
        "","","","",""
    ],
    []
];
```

### Logic:

The Logic is `array_filler()` function and `array_map()` function remove all unless element or array from data.

```
$data = array_filter(array_map(function ($record) {
    return array_filter(array_filter($record, function ($value) {
        return $value !== null || $value === 0.0 || $value === "0";
    }));
}, $records));

$data = array_filter($data);

print_r($data);
```

**How work:**

> $value !== null || $value === 0.0 || $value === "0"

the logic keep `0`,`"0"` elements and remove `''` or `null` elements

> $data = array_filter($data);

the logic remove empty arrays.