# Remove empty array elemnts from array without knowing keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have an array where I do not know what the keys are called and I am trying to remove all the items from array where all of the sub keys are empty (wihout value).

My array could look like this. The second element [1] has empty values so I would like to remove it and only leave the first element [0].

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Some key here] => 26542973
            [generated key] => John
            [who knows what key] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Some key here] => 
            [generated key] => 
            [who knows what key] => 
        )

)
```

I tried using array filter but it did not remove the empty element. It left both of them in the array.

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array);
```

I would like to have the end result look like this (empty element removed).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Some key here] => 26542973
            [generated key] => John
            [who knows what key] => 10
        )
)
```

Comment: So what should happen if only one of the sub elements are empty for example just `[Some key here]`

Comment: It should remove only if all sub elements are empty. I should update the question.

Comment: Have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895130/recursively-remove-empty-elements-and-subarrays-from-a-multi-dimensional-array as it covers quite a few scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_filter()` as shown in bottom. So you need to join items of inner array using `implode()` and check that result is empty or not.

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($val){
    return implode("", $val) != "";
});
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/sgeXB)

Comment: It left all of the empty ones and removed the ones with values (the opposite effect)

Comment: @Liga Bug fixed  :)

Comment: Does it require all sub items to be empty or just one?

Comment: @Liga All as you said.

Answer (score 4):

Use **[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)** with **[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).**

```
$array = array(array('data1','data1'), array('data2','data2'), array('','')); 
$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));
print_r($array);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/YvEMk)**

Comment: If you have `array('data3','')` this will remove the empty element, is that what is needed?